# Story where cities are trains that constantly move around the world

Tags: story-identification

There is a vague idea of a setting in my head, and I can not even remember whether I read a story with it, or was it a part of a game.

The only thing I remember is that there was a planet where nights (or days?) were so dangerous, that nobody could survive them even with stationary defenses. So instead, circular railroads were built around the planet, and people live in the trains always moving in the light.
The plot involved a civil war on one of the trains and one character making a motorized tram. He tried to charge through the night side of the planet, but found there another train of humans who believed that the opposite half of the day was deadly.

Google found me a couple of books where people migrate on trains regularly, but the key idea of this plot is that trains have almost no time to stop.

Comment: Kim Stanley Robinson's Blue Mars had a city on a train on the planet Mercury that stayed ahead of the burning dawn. People had to race through the day once to catch up. It doesn't match a few other of your points though.

Comment: This reminds me a bit of Christopher Priest's *The Inverted World* But that is clearly not the book the OP read.

Comment: @MikeC Robinson also [reused](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20220/does-2312-take-place-in-the-same-universe-as-the-mars-trilogy) that in 2312, but with that book, too, the other details from Barafu Albino's question don't fit.

Answer (score 2):

[*Snowpiercer*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706620/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt) (2013)?

> Survivors of Earth's second Ice Age live out their days on a luxury train that ploughs through snow and ice. The train's poorest residents, who live in the squalid caboose, plan to improve their lot by taking over the engine room.

Comment: I do not remember anything about snow, but I will read that.

Comment: I watched the movie, and while some elements of the plot match, there's only one train. There are 3-4 guys who decided to get out of the train and are seen frozen once a year, so the thing about survival matches. However there wasn't anything involving two sides of the planet (earth?) and two trains of people, each one knowing about the other. The wikipedia page for the movie however offers some inspirations (like Metro 2033) which could help identifying the correct book/movie/game

Comment: Per the rules on [referencing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) could you [edit] this to add in the link to the source of where the quote is from?